# How to use ARRAYFORMULA in query where clause?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In cell `C1:C` of my table I got 6 rows with ticket id's. I like to search different spreadsheets to search for those ticket id's and calculate the total hours spent on that ticket.

I have it working using the following formula:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"B3:B")\ARRAYFORMULA(TO_PURE_NUMBER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"F3:F")-IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"E3:E")))};"SELECT SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '"&C1&"' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")
```

*In this example, C1 is where the ticket ID can be found.*

Now I thought I could just wrap `QUERY` in a `ARRAYFORMULA` and use `C1:C` instead of just `C1` but that won't work. Now I could just copy and paste the above formula in every cell but there must be a cleaner way.

**ANSWER**

*I used the following formula to make it work, thanks to Max's answer below.*

```
=QUERY(
{
  IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"B3:B")\
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    TO_PURE_NUMBER(
      IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"F3:F") - IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEETID";"E3:E")
    )
  )
};
"
SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) 
WHERE Col1 = '" & JOIN("' OR Col1 = '";FILTER(C:C; C:C <> "")) & "' 
GROUP BY Col1 
LABEL SUM(Col2) ''
")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample formula is:

`=QUERY({A:B},"select * where Col1 = '"&JOIN("' or Col1 = '",FILTER(D2:D,D2:D<>""))&"'")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, one cannot create an array of query strings and use `arrayformula(query(...))` to run them all at once.

Alternative: instead of

```
SELECT SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '"&C1&"' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''
```

use the query

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1
```

elsewhere on the sheet, and then use `vlookup` to look up the sum for each value of Col1 that you want. `vlookup` can be used inside of `arrayformula` like this:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(C1:C10, E:F, 2, 0))
```

looks up each of values in C1..C10 in the column E (exact match required) and returns the corresponding value in column F (2nd column of the searched range).